# How to use conditional in SQL statement

Tags: sql-server

What I am trying to accomplish is `Group` column.

If a task has multiple users working on it, then I want to label as `Team` else `individual`.

```
Task    Sub-Task    User    Group
1234    9999             A  Team
1234    9998             B  Team
1234    9997             C  Team

2345    6666             A  Team
2345    6665             B  Team

3456    5555             A  Individual A
4567    4444             B  Individual B
5678    3333             C  Individual C
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of window function `OVER()`. When the `COUNT()` is more than 1 `Team` else `Individual`

```
select  *,
        case when count(User) over (partition by Task) > 1
             then 'Team' 
             else 'Individual' 
             end
from    yourtable
```

Comment: OP didn't mention a scenario like this, but if a task has multiple sub-tasks, but all are associated with a single user I'm guessing OP would want to see "Individual X" still instead of "Team" since indeed it was just one individual. I believe this query would flag as "Team" and unfortunately `count(...) over(...)` doesn't allow `count(DISTINCT ...) over (...)` to resolve that

Comment: Yes. We won't know if OP doesn't mention

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set up a derived table (either as a CTE or inline) that counts the number of users per task. You can then use this to show the group you need (pretty similar to @Squirrel's answer, just replacing the window function with a derived record set).

```
WITH
    TasksGroupedByUser(Task, UserCount) AS
    (
        SELECT Task, COUNT(DISTINCT [User])
        FROM Tasks
        GROUP BY Task
    )
SELECT
    Tasks.*,
    CASE
        WHEN TasksGroupedByUser.UserCount > 1 THEN 'Group'
        ELSE 'Individual' + ' ' + Tasks.[User]
    END
FROM Tasks
    INNER JOIN TasksGroupedByUser ON
        TasksGroupedByUser.Task = Tasks.Task
```

Comment: Thank you Zack. I will try both since I will be working with 20 million results and I forgot to add the I will also be doing Distinct Count on Task

Comment: At the time I'm looking at this, OP's example has the user appended to "Individual". I'm thinking you could just add `MAX(User)` to the `TasksGroupedByUser` CTE and then concatenate that to 'Individual'. Also I think changing `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT User)` would be better. I'm thinking of a scenario where the same user has multiple subtasks, but is still the only user for that task.

Comment: @EilertHjelmeseth: Thanks for your comment. I updated the answer to reflect your suggestions. Although I would argue that having sub-tasks as a 2nd column is bad design on the part of OP: I would have a `Task` attribute, then a `ParentTask` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Does this do what you want?

```
SELECT Task, SubTask, [User], [Group] = CASE WHEN GroupCount > 1 THEN 'Group' ELSE 'Individual' END
FROM (
    SELECT *, [GroupCount] = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TestTable AS B WHERE B.Task = A.Task)
    FROM TestTable AS A) AS C
```

Comment: I noticed that you said you were dealing with millions of records, it may be worth thinking about a trigger that updates and persists that field upon insert/update/delete if performance becomes to much of a burden.

Answer (score 0):

My 2 cents:

```
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
  [Id] BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
  [Task] INT,
  [SubTask] INT,
  [User] NCHAR(1),
  [Group] NVARCHAR(32)
)

INSERT INTO #tmp ([Task], [SubTask], [User], [Group]) VALUES (1234, 9999, 'A', 'Team');
INSERT INTO #tmp ([Task], [SubTask], [User], [Group]) VALUES (1234, 9998, 'B', 'Team');
INSERT INTO #tmp ([Task], [SubTask], [User], [Group]) VALUES (1234, 9997, 'C', 'Team');
INSERT INTO #tmp ([Task], [SubTask], [User], [Group]) VALUES (2345, 6666, 'A', 'Team');
INSERT INTO #tmp ([Task], [SubTask], [User], [Group]) VALUES (2345, 6665, 'B', 'Team');
INSERT INTO #tmp ([Task], [SubTask], [User], [Group]) VALUES (3456, 5555, 'A', 'Individual A');
INSERT INTO #tmp ([Task], [SubTask], [User], [Group]) VALUES (4567, 4444, 'B', 'Individual B');
INSERT INTO #tmp ([Task], [SubTask], [User], [Group]) VALUES (5678, 3333, 'C', 'Individual C');

SELECT          [A].[Task],
                [B].[SubTask],
                [B].[User],
                CASE [A].[Cnt]
                WHEN 1 THEN 'Individual ' + [User]
                ELSE 'Team'
                END AS [GroupCalculated],
                [Group],
                [A].[Cnt]

FROM (          SELECT          [Task],
                                COUNT(*) AS [Cnt]
                FROM            #tmp
                GROUP BY        [Task]) AS [A]

INNER JOIN      #Tmp AS [B]
    ON          [B].[Task] = [A].[Task];

DROP TABLE #tmp;
```

Comment: I think it'd be helpful to change `COUNT(*)` to `COUNT(DISTINCT User)` in case there are multiple sub tasks for the same user, but that user is still the only user for the task.

Answer (score 0):

Window functions are a great way to handle this. The tricky part with using the `COUNT` window function is it does not allow you to do `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)`. So if a user has 2 subtasks it'll return 2 when I'm guessing you'd want it to return 1.

However, we could use `MIN` and `MAX` window functions to see if there is only one user for a task.

`MIN([user]) OVER (PARTITION BY task)` will get the "minimum" user value per task in the result set. Likewise, `MAX` will get the "maximum". If they're the same that means there is only one user for that task, even if the same user has multiple subtasks.

```
SELECT
    task,
    subtask,
    [user],
    CASE
        WHEN MIN([user]) OVER (PARTITION BY task) = MAX([user]) OVER (PARTITION BY task)
        THEN 'Individual ' + [user]
        ELSE 'Team'
    END
FROM Tasks
```

Without window functions, this would be an appropriate way to do it also, which is similar to other answers, but I thought I'd include it here, noting that it only counts distinct users.

```
SELECT
    A.task,
    A.subtask,
    A.[user],
    CASE
        WHEN B.user_count = 1
        THEN 'Individual ' + [user]
        ELSE 'Team'
    END
FROM Tasks A 
INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT 
            task,
            COUNT(DISTINCT [user]) user_count
        FROM #tmp
        GROUP BY
            task
    ) B 
ON      A.task = B.task
```

Since you're planning to run this against a decently large table perhaps testing both solutions for performance might be helpful.

Comment: Thank u Eilert. I am trying all. Making me learn different way to solve a problem.